# I have a unique problem with RegEx. pattern search issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to find the words that are matching "cancel" "refund" etc

I have this regex

```
/(?:ref|ar|can|auto)/gmi
```

where it finds cancel and refund in a sentence and also it picks the word "can"
For e.g I would like to **cancel** my order and get a **refund**. **Can** I do that?

I just need the words that are used along with "can" in any form but exclude the word "can"?
Also, is it possible to find the set of words that has the reference of cancel, refund etc in a sentence using regex?

Please help!

Comment: Do you mea you want to find words that start with those prefixes? `/\b(?:ref|ar|can|auto)\w+/gi`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Only find the matches of "can" in prefix or suffix of a word but not just the word "can" alone.

Comment: So, something like `/\b(?!(?:ref|ar|can|auto)\b)\w*(?:ref|ar|can|auto)\w*/gi`?

Comment: Wow yeah, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! Is there a way in regex to perform a search in a sentence for the words that are related to refund/cancel only?

Comment: At this point, it seems to me you are looking for some NLP solution.